# Show element only if value matches in JSON array

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to display element only if the `uid` exist in JSON array:

i've tried it so far:

```
var app = agular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function () {
    $scope.uid = '10';
    $scope.datas = [{
        'id': '1',
        'name': 'abc'
    }, {
        'id': '2',
        'name': 'xyz'
    }];
});



<p ng-if="datas.length | filter:{id: uid}">ID exist in array</p>
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jaym0403/USrdt/4/)

Answer (score 5):

you can define function on scope that would that for u (and use filter service inside)

i.e.

```
<div ng-app="mod">
    <div ng-controller='MCtrl'>
       <p ng-show="exists(1)">ID exist in array</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
mod.controller('MCtrl', function($scope, $filter){
    var items = [123,2,1]
    $scope.exists = function(val){
        return $filter('filter')(items, val).length > 0;;;
    }  
});
```

if you'd like to do it in view

```
<p ng-show="(items|filter:1:true).length > 0">ID exist in array</p>
```

btw, true means it should be exact match

Comment: i tried but didn't work. If you can then Update my fiddle and give me live example.

Answer (score 4):

Hi please see here:  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2JJxL/)

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <p ng-show="check()">ID exist in array</p>
        <p ng-hide="check()">ID NOT exist in array</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.uid = '2';
    $scope.datas = [{
        'id': '1',
            'name': 'abc'
    }, {
        'id': '2',
            'name': 'xyz'
    }];


    $scope.check = function () {
        var ifExist = false;
        angular.forEach($scope.datas, function (data) {

            if (data.id == $scope.uid)

            ifExist = true;



        });
        return ifExist;

    }
});
```